# Unable to find available subscriptions for all your installed products in redhat 6.10

Tags: redhat

I had install redhat 6.10 on vmware. after I subscribed the redhat repos, it show me output as below:
"Unable to find available subscriptions for all your installed products in redhat 6.10"

Comment: RHEL 6.10 has been [End of Life for over two years](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4768501). Upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [RedHat site](https://access.redhat.com/product-life-cycles/?product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux,OpenShift%20Container%20Platform%204) you are out of support.

The only way is to subscribe to Extended life cycle support which will end June 30, 2024.

Or migrate to newer version of the operating system